# Android dialer does not show call history

Tags: phone-app, call-history, oneplus

I am using a One Plus 9R and somehow I cannot see the call history for callers.

In all my past Android phones I used to be able to get a list of past call times and durations etc by clicking on a particular caller name.

Any idea what could be wrong? I seem to be having the "Phone by Google" app installed and presumably that's my dialer.

I tried clearing the cache for that app. Anything else I should be trying?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for:**  ... can't see call history for callers.

I'm not familiar with One Plus 9R, However I can say that stock dialers on most phones are feature lite. My advice if you want to see call history for callers is to replace your stock dialer with a dialer app from playstore etc.. The advantage of replacing your stock dialer with a 3rd party app dialer is that whenever you get a new phone you can install the same dialer app you are familiar with. FYI: I used the Free version of the following dialer for years. I liked is so well i did buy the premium version, but that is up to you. This dialer has call history, time of day, how long you talked, if person called you or you called them, even shows calls I missed or that did not get picked up on the other side + so much more. There are other dialers too.. but for me.. I like this app called:  **[True Phone Dialer & Contacts & call Recorder by Hamster Beat]** There are other dialer apps. See which one you like the best. The one mentioned above is just the one I liked.

**Note:** After you download this or any phone app.. be sure to change the **{Default App Setting]** on you phone.

**goto** your phone **[Settings]**.. usually the icon that looks like a gear.

#1 Press the Gear icon to access settings.

#2 near top is a magnifying glass for SEARCH

#3 Search in settings for **[Default apps]**

#4 On the Default Apps page, tap on **[Phone app]**

#5 Select the App you want to use as your default phone app

#6 then back out using the arrow on top pointing left..

#7 exit the setup section as you normally would do.

Replacing your stock phone app with a 3rd party phone app will solve your call history needs + the advantage of having the same familiar dialer on any future phone you use.  Hope this answer is Helpful..  Good Luck  :)